# Change iPhone user agent?

Tags: iphone, user-agent

I need to view a site with an iPhone but it redirects me to the mobile version. How can I prevent this redirection? Is the only way to hide or change my user agent? If so how can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a developer question, but:

1/ use an alternate browser such as iCabMobile, IIRC it allows you to change the user-agent;

2/ on most "mobile" sites, at the very bottom of the page, there's a "classic view" or "desktop view" link.